# UPDATE tbl SET field = x WHERE field != x?

Tags: mysql, sql

Are there any performance gain with this query:

```
UPDATE tbl SET field = 1 WHERE field != 1
```

over this

```
UPDATE tbl SET field = 1
```

Does the SQL parser already know that he doenst' need to update row that already are field = 1 ?

Comment: Funny: it seems to me that there are arguments for the unconditional form being actually *faster*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are just a few fields which are `!= 1`, then there are most definitely performance gains in adding the `WHERE` clause. Even if MySQL did not *write* the value to disk, it still would need to look at every row to see if it needs to write it or not, but it certainly does not add the `WHERE` clause by itself.

Comment: @yes123, from what I tested, yes. Huge performance difference on a very large table.

Comment: I suspected that indeed, that's why i posted this. thanks for testing

Answer (score 4):

The condition `field != 1` will likely make it faster especially in the case where most values are already 1.  Assuming an index is available for optimizing, the database engine will be able to avoid examining most of the records in that case.

More importantly, perhaps, is that the queries may not have the same result.  If any of the `field` values are NULL, the first UPDATE statement will not update those values.  The second query would set the NULLs to `1`.

Another (fairly obvious) case where they would not be equivalent is that UPDATE triggers would fire for all records for the second query (without the condition) but they would not fire for the first query for the skipped rows.

Comment: Avoid examining? It can be argued that on the contrary, you just told it that it *needs* to examine the value in every row. Can you elaborate?